# comparing php timestamp with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
$_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
```

in php.

I'm trying to 'inject' it to jquery:

```
var sesstime = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['CREATED']) ?>;
```

Now i want to current date:

```
var timestampjq = (new Date()).getTime();
```

And how to format these dates ?

I want to use:

```
if(timestampjq - sesstime > 60) {

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

`Date.getTime()` returns milliseconds ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)), while PHP's `time()` function returns seconds ([documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)), so you can't directly compare them.

If you want to be able to directly compare them, you must first divide the JS timestamp by 1000:

```
if (timestampjq/1000 - sesstime > 60) {...}
```

Or if you want to be really precise, you can use PHP's `microtime()` function too, but need to keep in mind that it returns a `float` - milliseconds are after the decimal separator):

```
// In PHP:
$_SESSION['CREATED'] = microtime(true)*1000;

...

// In JS:
if (timestampjq - sesstime > 60*1000) {...}
```